# Angular :The specified value "2022-03-30T00:00:00.000+00:00" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to put a date from my database to my input `type="date"` field. Strings works perfectly, they all go to form when  except date.

My input type is date on the form.

### my form :

```
  <input  [value]="candidat.birthDate" type="date">
```

---

### candidat:

```
export class Candidat {
     birthDate!:Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a general HTML input error

When you use `type="date"` in you input element, you have to comply to its [expected values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).
The specification illustrates that:

> value includes the year, month, and day, but not the time. The time and datetime-local input types support time and date+time input

So to make it work you need to adjust datTime string `2022-03-30T00:00:00.000+00:00` you are using. Using the first 10 chars should do the trick:

```
<input  [value]="candidat.birthDate?.substr(0,10)" type="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't use pipe, just like below:

```
<input  value={{candidat.birthDate | date}} type="date">
```